# Sinon stub doesn't seem to work when object destructuring is used

Tags: node.js, sinon

Let's say you have a method called `myMethod` in the module `myModule` which is looking like this:

```
function myMethod() {
   return 5;
}
module.exports.myMethod = myMethod;
```

Now if I want to stub this method to return 2 instead of 5 with Sinon I would write

```
const myModule = require('path/myModule');
sinon.stub(myModule, 'myMethod').returns(2);
```

Now in the place where you actually call the method you happen to import the method like this with object destruction

```
const { myMethod } = require('path/myModule');
console.log(myMethod()); // Will print 5
```

If you do that, `myMethod` is actually not stubbed and won't return 2 but 5 instead.

If you instead require again the module and use the function from the required module it will work

```
const myModule= require('path/myModule');
console.log(myModule.myMethod()); // Will print 2
```

Is there anyone who has a solution to this other than just changing the way I import my functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stubbed `myMethod` will have a different reference than the original method. In the destructuring example, you are setting the reference before it can be stubbed.

```
// cannot be stubbed
const { myMethod } = require('path/myModule');

// can be stubbed
const myModule = require('path/myModule');
myModule.myMethod();
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587999/sinon-stub-function-used-with-destructuring) similar question for more details

Comment: So, in this case, it seems like there is no other way but refactoring my imports because of the different references?

Comment: That's how i'm interpreting it, yeah - you would need to place the destructuring closer to the invocation of the function rather than at module initialization in order for the reference to the stub to appear after initialization

Comment: makes sense, Thanks a lot!

Comment: "No other way" is a bit too restrictive. You could target the link seams, meaning you hooked into the module loading using proxyquire or rewire. That has nothing to do with Sinon in itself though.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.

Just note that as soon as this runs:

```js
const { myMethod } = require('./lib');
```

...it will remember whatever `myMethod` was at that moment.

So, you just have to make sure you set up the stub *before that code runs*.

---

So for this `lib.js`:

```js
function myMethod() {
  return 5;
}
module.exports.myMethod = myMethod;
```

and this `code.js`:

```js
const { myMethod } = require('./lib');
console.log(myMethod());
```

you would just need to do this:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

const myModule = require('./lib');
sinon.stub(myModule, 'myMethod').returns(2);  // set up the stub FIRST...
require('./code');  // ...THEN require the code (prints "2")
```