# why the stubbed functions does not works when using destructor with sinon js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

There are a lot of people face the problem of stubing functions with sinon.js doesn't work when using `destructor`and there is a great explantion mentioned on [Sinon stub function used with destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587999/sinon-stub-function-used-with-destructuring/52591287#52591287).
And as mentioned in the answer, when using the destructor we call always the original function:

```
const stub = (o, method) => (o[method] = () => "I am a stub");

const obj = {
  methodFoo() {
    return "I am foo";
  }
};

// same as doing `const methodFoo = obj.methodFoo;`
const { methodFoo } = obj; // "import" using destructuring

console.log("obj.methodFoo(): ", obj.methodFoo());
console.log("methodFoo()", methodFoo());

console.log("Stubbing out method!");
stub(obj, "methodFoo");

console.log("obj.methodFoo: ", obj.methodFoo());
console.log("methodFoo()", methodFoo());
```

I searched for an answer why the `destructor` overrides the `stub` or how it works under the hood to understand how to manipulate data but I didn't get any solution. Is there any details about this issue ?

Comment: JavaScript uses assign/copy **by value**. `const { methodFoo } = obj;` assigns a copy of the value that `obj.methodFoo` has to `methodFoo`, which is a reference to a function. After that, any changes to `obj.methodFoo` won't affect the variable `methodFoo`. This is not specific to destructuring though. That's how assignment, variables and values work in JS. Here is a sightly simpler example: `var obj = {foo() { console.log('foo'); }; var method = obj.foo; obj.foo = () => console.log('bar'); method();`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stubbing overrides the methods property. If you take this contrived example:

```
 const obj = { prop: "value" };

 const prop = obj.prop; // or { prop } = obj;

 obj.prop = "new value"; // stub()

 console.log(prop); // "value"
```

then it might become clearer. Think of methods as values that can be copied (actually a reference to them gets copied).