# Is it possible to stub an exported function in a CommonJS module using sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, sinon, commonjs

In almost 2021, is there a way to mock a single function? I mean function without object.

```
// demo.js
module.exports = () => {
  return 'real func demo';
};

// demo.test.js
const demo = require("./demo");
// ...
sinon.stub(demo).callsFake(() => {
  return 'mocked function';
});
expect(demo()).to.eq('mocked function')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562#issuecomment-753321689

Comment: It's almost 2024. Would be cool if you could accept an answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just [quote myself](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562#issuecomment-863521301) here:

You cannot stub standalone exported functions in an ES2015 compliant module (ESM) nor a CommonJS module in Node. That is just how these module systems work. It's only after transforming them into *something else* you *might* be able to achieve what you want. How you replace modules is totally environment specific and is why Sinon touts itself as "Standalone test spies, stubs and mocks for JavaScript" and *not* a module replacement tool, as that is better left to environment specific utils (proxyquire, various webpack loaders, Jest, etc) for whatever env you are in.

For a more deep-dive into why this will *never* work in CommonJS when using destructuring, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587999/sinon-stub-function-used-with-destructuring/52591287#52591287). You need to inject a module loader that intercepts the loading.

This is what trying to use Sinon to stub out an ESM module looks like in a spec compliant environment:

```
$ node esm-stubbing.mjs
/private/tmp/test/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:72
        throw new TypeError("ES Modules cannot be stubbed");
              ^

TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed
    at Function.stub (/private/tmp/test/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:72:15)
    at Sandbox.stub (/private/tmp/test/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox.js:388:37)
    at file:///private/tmp/test/esm-stubbing.mjs:4:7

$ cat esm-stubbing.mjs
import sinon from "sinon";
import * as myModule from "./module.mjs";

sinon.stub(myModule, "foo").returns(42);
```

This is just Sinon itself throwing an error when it sees that the namespace of the module is read-only, instead of letting Node throw a more cryptic error message.

Answer (score -1):

you can import with `as` syntax.

if you exported as `default` then use 'default' instead of the actual name

```
import * as yourModule from '../<path>';
    
const fake = sinon.fake.returns(<value>);
sinon.replace(yourModule, 'default', fake);
```

Comment: He is using CommonJS. It's in the tags. You are using EcmaScript Modules, which is a totallly different module loader with different semantics. 

And as I write [on the Sinon tracker](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562#issuecomment-861302228), this is only possible if your environment is NOT spec compliant. Your "trick" would not work with Node, for instance, without being transpiled to something else. Check the Sinon tests for es2015 for a reference.